# How to close all secondary Outlook windows?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

I use Outlook for mailing and often click on a new mail ticker to open the mail and briefly read it. Once read, I also often forget to close the mail view window and just change the focus on my main working application.
At the end of the working day I have 20-30 secondary mail view windows cluttering all around my desktop, and the only way I can get rid of them is to close the mother application and re-open it.

Is there any better way to accomplish this task without restarting Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

If by *better* you mean *faster*, then the answer is No.  Closing Outlook and thereby performing 30 simultaneous close actions at once is indeed the *fastest* way to accomplish this task.